# Distributing Android Apps to enterprise (Volume Purchase Program like)

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if there is a kind of Enterprise Program to distribute Apps on Google Play. I know the Volume Purchase Program of Apple to distribute apps to enterprise (you sell a number of licences of your app to an enterprise and their employees will be able to download 
it quickly without buying it as the company already paid for it).

How to do it with Android apps ?
Should we distribute the .apk ourselves to the company by-passing the Google Play ? I don't think so, but I cannot figure out how to do it...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best place to get an answer about a corporate service (such as Google Play). If it is not in the docs, most probably it's not currently available (or at least publicly available). You might want to contact Google to ask directly.

If it turns out there is no such option, you need to build your own distribution channel (email, download from website, pre-installing on devices, etc.) and possibly licensing scheme.

Comment: As I found similar questions concerning the AppStore I thought that was the place for that. I was wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is Google Play Private Channel:
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992

It *seems* to require the receiving users to get their google account from the distributor.